# SyntaxError loading launchChrome.js in react-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I am trying to use react-native and react-native-weback-server.

When I run `rnws start` I get a SyntaxError at `node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/util/launchChrome.js:15`

```
function getChromeAppName(): string {
                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Looking at that file, I see the method:

```
function getChromeAppName(): string {
  switch (process.platform) {
  case 'darwin':
    return 'google chrome';
  case 'win32':
    return 'chrome';
  default:
    return 'google-chrome';
  }
}
```

However this does not with my Node version (7.9.0). I don't know what version of Javascript this is valid syntax in and if I'm using the correct babel transpiler.

Here's my NPM dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "coffee-script": "^1.12.5",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-native": "^0.43.3",
    "react-native-webpack-server": "^0.9.3",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  }
```

and webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: './app.coffee',
  output: { filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2016', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.coffee$/,
        loader: "coffee-loader" 
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [Flow](https://flow.org/).

Flow syntax files usually have a `@flow` comment at the head, as you can see [this file does](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/2cc57d05a414dccca8874132424e04a6b92bce8e/local-cli/server/util/launchChrome.js#L9).

There is [a Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-flow/) to enable parsing this syntax.

Comment: I added the babel-plugin-syntax-flow and also put it in the babelrc, but the error is still happening. Is there something I have to change with the webpack file?

Comment: @maxple I'm not sure. Did you try adding `plugins: ["syntax-flow"]` to your `query` options?

Comment: what do you mean 'query options'? I just put `{"plugins": ["syntax-flow"]}` in babelrc

Comment: @maxple In your `webpack.config.js` file you have a `query` object with your `presets`. You might need to list your plugins there too. I don't know if babel-loader reads the babelrc file.

Comment: I'm still trying with this. I gotta say I find it a little annoying that react-native source code is distributed in a precompiled state. Since it all gets turned into browser-compatible JS anyway, why not ship it with plain js for those who aren't using flow? Not asking for an answer, just griping.